# ReportingService2005 API

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

How i can get list of parameters from report using ReportingService2005 API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetReportParameters?

[Example](http://odetocode.com/Articles/123.aspx) and [another](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bryanke/archive/2004/07/29/200914.aspx)